# HTML and CSS Table Design Question - Have a div span across multiple cells?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to design the table below (see below UI design). However, I cant seem to find a way to render it in HTML and CSS as depending on the information received from the API, the working hours may range. Hence, I don't know how to create the styles to create a continuous bar (with a shadow) and have to resizable. I don't think a HTML table will work as styling a value that spans between cells didn't seem to work. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't post any code of what you have tried, but generally speaking, you could achieve that by having same-width `inline-block` elements for the time indications at the top for the continuous bars use divs which have `position: absolute` (with their white background as relative-position parents/anchor elements) that have according percentage `left`/`right` values to determine the start and end points, a fixed `height`, a `border-radius` which is half of the height, `background-color`, `border`and `box-shadow` as desired, and `text-align: center` to center their text-content.